# What if someone got a demon slayer mark after they'd already turned 25?

Tags: demon-slayer

What would happen if someone got a demon slayer mark after they'd already turned 25? Would they die straight away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we know if mark appeared before age of 25 person dies at age of 25, but in some cases that's not true. So if anyone acquires the mark after age of 25 he/she may live. In other cases mark consumes life energy so he/she may die in fight or how much energy they use.

Answer (score 2):

According to what the [wiki](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Demon_Slayer_Mark) says:

> Having the Demon Slayer Mark has its costs. Demon Slayers who have awakened the Demon Slayer Mark are said to die upon reaching the age of 25.

and also it is said:

> Kokushibo speculated this to be because the mark exchanged the life span of its user for power.

if the first theory is the right one,

> the user will immediately die after awakening the demon slayer mark if he/she is older than 25

but if what Kokushibo said is true,

> they can live longer and become older than 25.

side note based on [wiki](https://kimetsu-no-yaiba.fandom.com/wiki/Demon_Slayer_Mark):

> Yoriichi was able to defy fate and lived to be 85 years old